# Creating a vertical spacing autolayout constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I've got an autolayout constraint that attaches a view just above the tab bar. The specifics of this aren't important, it works fine.

```
NSDictionary *views = @{@"view":self.collectionSelectionContainer, @"bottomLayoutGuide":self.bottomLayoutGuide};
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"offset":@(tabBarHeight)};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view]-offset-[bottomLayoutGuide]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

However, I want to create this constraint using the other method:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]
```

I've tried various ways unsuccessfully. Can anybody show me how?

Thanks

Comment: Hey mate, out of interest why aren't you connecting the bottom of 'collectionSelectionContainer' to the top of the 'tabBar' ?

Comment: Ey up Mike.... My layout constraints are in a view controller that is in a containment hierarchy. So attempting to add the constraint to the tab bar, which isn't a descendant of my view, violates the rules.

Comment: Ah, sounds complicated ... sure beats setting frames though eh! :)

Answer (score 2):

I figured that I could just inspect the NSLayoutConstraint returned array from constraintsWithVisualFormat! This actually was a great way to figure it out and then build the method from there:

The answer is this:

```
self.collectionSelectionBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.collectionSelectionContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:tabBarHeight];
[self.view addConstraint:self.collectionSelectionBottomConstraint];
```

I think the reason I was being unsuccessful before was that I was passing 0 as the multiplier.

Comment: I had to use `Top` instead of `TopMargin`. That was the error in my case.